# Is there a way that I can find the source package of a file in CentOS without using yum?

Tags: centos, package-management, opengl

I'm trying to find the source package for libglut.so.

I found this website that explains how to do it in ubuntu:https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file

But I need to know how to do it in CentOS.

My system is CentOS 6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have the package installed, `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib64/libglut.so.3` will show the name of the package providing the file.

(Inapplicable as you don't want to use yum) : if not already installed, then `yum provides /usr/lib64/libglut.so.3` or simply `yum provides 'libglut*'` will search the yum repos and provides the information.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `yum`:

```
yum provides */libglut.so
```